# Complex event creation

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, registration

Setting up a complex event in either CiviEvent or webform

There are three time slots and 5-6 sessions/time slot. Each of those sessions would have a max participation count that when reached, the system would no longer show it as an option to pick.

Would I have to set up three different price sets and events in order to achieve the max participation rule, or is there a way using a webform that the max participation can be enforced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE!

If I understand your scenario correctly there  are three time slots and you want participants to choose a session in each one. You can accomplish this with a single price set and a price field for each time slot using radio buttons for the line items (session options). You can set Max Participants for each line item. Once that is reached the line item option will become unavailable.

The Extended Reports extension has a line item report which is handy for getting counts per session.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I should have though of that, I was experimenting in there earlier and my brain didn't want to connect the dots.